# Entity Framework Code First- Two nullable and one non-null foreign keys from same table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, nullable, entity-framework-migrations

How can I set correct structure for this question between these two table and columns?
Thank you.

**Tasks table:**

```
public int EntryUserId{get;set;}
public virtual Users EntryUser{get;set;}

public int? AssignToUserId{get;set;}
public virtual Users AssignToUser{get;set;}

public int? CheckerUserId{get;set;}
public virtual Users CheckerUser{get;set;}
```

**Users Table:**

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Tasks> EntryUser
public virtual ICollection<Tasks> AssignToUser
public virtual ICollection<Tasks> CheckerUser
```

**In my DbContext Class:**

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tasks>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.EntrybyUser)
                .WithMany(t => t.EntryUser)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.EntryUserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Tasks>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.AssignToUser)
                .WithMany(t => t.AssignToUser)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.AssignToUserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);//for nullable

    modelBuilder.Entity<Tasks>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.CheckerUser)
                .WithMany(t => t.CheckerUser)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.CheckerUserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);//for nullable
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tasks>()
                    .HasRequired(m => m.EntryUser)
                    .WithMany(m=> m.EntryUser)
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.EntryUserId)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Tasks>()
                    .HasOptional(m => m.AssignToUser)
                    .WithMany(t => t.AssignToUser)
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.AssignToUserId)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);//for nullable

        modelBuilder.Entity<Tasks>()
                    .HasOptional(m => m.CheckerUser)
                    .WithMany(t => t.CheckerUser)
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.CheckerUserId)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);//for nullable
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
```

and Users class to:

```
public class Users
{
    public virtual ICollection<Tasks> EntryUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tasks> AssignToUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tasks> CheckerUser { get; set; }
}
```